# Is there an iCloud web api?

Tags: oauth-2.0, icloud, icloud-api

I'd like to be able to access a user's iCal and create events from my server, is this possible, preferably with some kind of OAuth2 setup like with Google Calendar? If so where can I find documentation on the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no. There is currently no OAuth whatsoever for iCloud. However, there are two solutions to consider:

1. Ask the user for their AppleID and password and store it on your server (not recommended for security reasons). This will allow access to EVERYTHING the user has enabled on their account; even the ability to log in and purchase content - thus the security issue. But it will give you direct access to iCal.
2. Ask the user for access to calendar through your app. Using EKEventStore requestAccessToEntityType: method you can gain access to the users local calendar. You could batch those events and send them to your server. You can find information on how to access calendar [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. iCloud supports [CalDAV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791) on `caldav.icloud.com`, and that quite well. It allows you to create, modify and delete events and tasks. Unfortunately you have to have the user's credentials for this though.

Comment: Can CalDAV be used to retrieve iCloud contacts? Or is it limited to the calendar?

Comment: For that CardDAV exists.

Comment: Is there documentation on how to use CardDAV with iCloud?